# How to keep the Google place after coming back from another page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using google autocomplete textbox and a map to show the place entered in the textbox. following code will work on button click to show map.

```
                function SetStreet() {
                    $('#map-canvas').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        if (checkPlace == "placeselected") {
                            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                            map.setZoom(15);
                            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                            marker.setVisible(true);                                
                        }
                    });
                }
```

When i navigate to another page and comes back, currently map not showing the place.Is there any way to keep the

```
place.geometry.location
```

and to show the place in map again with out triggering google maps textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Store the textbox value in cookie and each time when your page gets loaded, just check for the cookie value and call the map function with that value if cookie is not null. Best way. 
Just try and let me know.

Comment: Ya its a good idea.I have tried session and it is working fine now

Comment: better to use cookie, because if you publish your application in distributed system like cloud, then session won't work.